# How to recognize a a http error code from within GWT?

Tags: gwt, gxt

When my users try to do an action our website after their session has expired (for instance, if they left their browser open), the server responds with a HTTP Status 405 because the user is no longer logged in.

When this happens, I want to redirect the user to the login screen.

How can I recognize when a 405 error code is returned within GWT so I can then redirect the users?

Thanks

**Edit:** 
Here's the filter I'm using:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            boolean isLoggedIn = CustomSecurity.login((HttpServletRequest)req);
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                // TODO: How to redirect the user here???
                }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

**web.xml** content:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

How can I make that redirect the user?  Also, is there a way to force the whole browser to redirect?  Since this goes into a widget, I think a Window.Location.assign('url') will only redirect the widget's HTML content.

Comment: Are you using GWT-RPC or RequestBuilder?

Comment: this filter approach will only redirect your rpc call if the session expires, you need to return the 405 to the client. if you redirect in the filter it will get a 200 but the endpoint will have changed and gwt wont be able to parse the data.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking the wrong way... but I want to redirect the user when the session expires as a 'catchall' so I don't have to go back and check in every RPC call whether the user is still logged in.  Perhaps

Comment: If you send a redirect to an HTML page as the response to an RPC request, wont that trip the browser up because it requested javascript  /Ajax content and received an HTML document as the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently work on a GWT application that does something very similar to what you are asking. However, we handle these redirects in a standard javax.servlet.Filter subclass that we define in our web.xml as per usual and it is mapped to /* so it catches all requests (we use this filter for many other reasons as well).

I don't know if you are also using a Filter or perhaps even just some sort of catch-all Servlet in your GWT app, but if you are then the solution to your issue is quite easy. You will have a handle to the HttpServletRequest and you can see if the getSession(false) method returns null then you know that the user who sent the request no longer has a session. Then you can just do a standard response.sendRedirect(...) to your login page.

Comment: This is over complicating things and is also making the assumption that he is using a Java server. There are much more simple pure GWT solutions depending on which method is being used to make the request (GWT-RPC or RequestBuilder).  The only method that doesn't allow for a pure GWT solution is JSONP due to the inability for response headers to make it through the padding layer, in which case your solution would be useful so you could return a response in JSONP format instead of JsonpRequiestBuilder timing out and a generic exception being thrown.

Comment: I believe this is the exact approach I need.  Can you please look at the updated question and recommend how to redirect the user when they're not logged in?

Comment: @Cuga, should be one quick extra step and then you are done. Where you have put the TODO in your code, try add the following: ((HttpServletResponse)res).sendRedirect("loginPageName"). I also assume that the if-statement you have should be "if (!isLoggedIn)" not "if (isLoggedIn)".

Comment: I don't understand how this would work in the client for RPC Ajax requests. Won't the RPC requests expect some serialized data response and receive a redirect to an HTML page? That's what happens to our GWT apps due to Shibboleth.

Answer (score 2):

For GWT-RPC you will get a [StatusCodeException](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/StatusCodeException.html) whenever the server returns anything but a 200 response code.  The status code can be retrieved from the exception and you can redirect via GWT by using Window.Location.assign(url).  For RequestBuilder the status code cqan be accessed via response.getStatusCode().

**EDIT**: Here is code to redirect if GWT's window isn't that root window.

```
private native void redirect(String url)/*-{
  var win = $wnd;
  while (win.parent != null && win.parent != win)
    win = win.parent;
  win.location = url;
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to redirect the entire browser?  My code is inside a widget, so doing Window.Location.assign() will only redirect that widget... and I want to redirect the entire page

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense... Unless the widget is inside and iFrame, but I will add some code to my answer that will work for situations where you might not be running in the root window.

Comment: That's exactly where they are-- inside an iframe.  Thanks for the code.

Comment: But how to get response body? I guess GWT replaces it with its own "The call failed on the server; see server log for details".

Comment: @SimonLogic Not sure what you are asking and how it relates to the original question. This is for if the server is returning a bad response code; the response body doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

In your [RequestCallback](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestCallback.html) implementation, you can check `response.getStatusCode()`.  We have [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) on the backend, which is wired up to force the user to a form based login page if they are not authenticated.  Upon authentication, it redirects them back.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
  if (SC_UNAUTHORIZED == response.getStatusCode()) {
    Window.Location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a try / catch for coders sakes!

```
AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            try {
                throw caught;
            } catch (StatusCodeException statusCodeException) {
                Util.handleException(statusCodeException);
            } catch (Throwable exception) {
                Util.handleException(exception);
            }
        }

        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            Window.alert("Result : " + result);
        }
    };
```

then to process your results

```
final static public void handleException(StatusCodeException exception) {
        String errorMessage = exception.toString() + 
                              "\n CODE: " + exception.getStatusCode() + 
                              "\n MESSAGE: " + exception.getEncodedResponse();
        Window.alert("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
    }    
final static public void handleException(Throwable exception) {
        String errorMessage = exception.toString() + "\n";
        for (StackTraceElement trace : exception.getStackTrace()) {
            errorMessage += trace.getClassName() + " :: " + 
                            trace.getMethodName() + " :: " + 
                            trace.getLineNumber() + "\n";
        }
        Window.alert("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
    }
```

remember that overloading is your friend! Dont forgot that if you do not compile your code in detailed or pretty you will get garbage for the stack trace. Unless of course someone figured out how to hack the JSStackEmulation class

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions